# Dialogflow: move to specific intent

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm developing a chatbot in Dialogflow and, in order to make it easier to me to get the parameters I need, I would like to "force" the conversation to go to a specific intent, where those parameters are required.

As far as I've seen, there is no way to move between intents as there is no such thing as a "flow" between them, but is there any other way to try to force my system to fall into a specific intent?

I'm not sure about how Contexts and Events work, so maybe using those functionalities?

In my case, I start the conversation in the Welcome intent, as usual, and then I say "I want to make an enquiry". This sends me to an "initicialization" that as me to enter my user name. Here is where I would like to go to my specific "user" intent, where the user name and other parameters are required in Actions and Parameters.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Are you trying to trigger an intent based on the user name? I mean you are expecting to have a specific intent for each user. Otherwise, are you looking to trigger a specific intent called "user" when you enter a user name? if possible, to better understand what you're expecting also add/clarify the example of the flow you want in the question

Comment: Hi! I actually solved my issue redifining the training phrases of my intents so the intents where trigger properly depending of the info I enter in Dialogflow :)